# Esper rule language: using timer for rule

Tags: java, rule-engine, complex-event-processing, esper

I want to write a rule in Esper that fires when the number of steps is 0 in the last 15 minutes and heart rate is above 120. I've come up with the following rule:

```
EPStatement cepStatementRule8 = cepRule.createEPL("context PartitionByMacSteps select * from "
                + "Steps.win:time(15 min) S, HeartRate.win:time(1 min) H "
                + "having (max(S.steps)-min(S.steps) = 0) and (H.heartrate > 120)");
        cepStatementRule8.addListener(new rule8Listener());
```

My HeartRate class has the following fields:

```
int heartrate;
String heartratesTimestamp;
String macAddress;
```

And my Steps class has these fields:

```
int steps;
String stepsTimestamp;
String macAddress;
```

The problem I face is that I only want the rule to fire if no steps are taken in the last 15 minutes. Now it fires when two step events have the samen amount of steps. I know that I probably have to use timer.interval but I couldn't figure out how to write this rule. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

The requirements are poorly defined. What does "heart rate is above 120" means really, is it just once or for 15 minutes or 1 minute and in addition how does "heart rate is above 120" overlap or be coincidental with the steps condition.

I'd recommend breaking down the problem into two independent condition detection and then a join to detect that both conditions occurred at some time. This also makes it easy to test as you can see each condition be indicated separately. for example something roughly like this:

```
// detect the steps condition
insert into StepConditionDetected 
select *, current_timestamp as detectedTime select * from pattern[...];

// detect the heartrate condition
insert into HeartrateConditionDetected 
select *, current_timestamp as detectedTime from pattern[...];

// join step and heartrate condition to see if they co-occur in some way
select * from StepConditionDetected.std:unique(macAddress).win:time(15 min) as a,
HeartrateConditionDetected.std:unique(macAddress).win:time(15 min) as b
where a.macAddress = b.macAddress
```

You could add to the where-clause joining the two conditions and use "overlap" to   implement some Allen interval algebra i.e. "and a.detecttime.overlaps(b.detectedTime, x, y)"

Comment: What I want is if no steps are taken in the last 15 minutes and after this 15 minutes the heart rate is higher then 120 the rule fires.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the step condition has to come first and only once that is found then begin looking for the heart rate condition? I.e. if there is no step condition then we don't need to look for heart rate? One solution could just always look for both conditions and use the join like before, could check with "after" in "where" for example. If you want to indicate to the engine should  only start anallyzing heartbeats when the step condition occurs then use a context "initiated by s=StepCondition terminate after 15 minutes" and have that context control the heartrate statements.

Comment: Yes the step condition needs to come first. But could you just give me an example how to write the StepCondition because I don't now how write rules with a timer.